# Safe way to cast (V)C++ long* to C# Int32*?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I'm currently writing a DLL in C++/CLI which will act as "proxy" between an unmanaged program and another C# DLL. The calling program requires my "proxy DLL" to implement various procedures that will be called by the unmanaged program. So far, no problem.

But: One of the functions has the following prototype:

```c
extern "C" __declspec ( dllexport ) long Execute(unsigned long command, long nInBytes, byte bInData[], long nOutBytes, long* pnUsedOutBytes, byte bOutData[])
```

Well, my proxy DLL simply calls the C# DLL which provides the following function prototype (which was also given by the documentation of the calling program):

```cs
unsafe public UInt32 Execute(UInt32 command, Int32 nInBytes, byte* pInData, Int32 nOutBytes, Int32* pnUsedOutBytes, byte* pOutData);
```

The compiler throws an error (C2664) at parameter 5 `pnUsedOutBytes` and tells me, that `long*` cannot be cast to `int*`. Well OK, `long` and `int` currently have the same implementation which might change at some point in the future, so the thrown error is understandable (though the non-pointer long uses do not throw an error?).

Back to the actual question: What is the best solution to call my C# function? I've already read that (of course) the best solution is to use .NET types when calling a .NET function. So: Is it safe to do a simple type casting when calling the function or might there by any bad circumstance where this type cast will not work?

Using this line calms down the compiler, but is it really safe?

```cs
curInstance->Execute(command, nInBytes, pInData, nOutBytes, (System::Int32*)pnUsedOutBytes, pOutData);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure it's more safe to use .NET types. Is there any reason for not using them in your case?

Comment: `long` and `int` in C# do NOT have the same size, which is why you are getting that error.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: C# `long` is not being used here, anywhere.

Comment: Whoever wrote that function signature in C# needs to be demoted to entry-level programmer.  The correct signature in C# would be `out Int32`, not `Int32*`.  Send a bug report upstream to whoever provided that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't use that cast. Suppose that the actual value that `pnUsedOutBytes` was greater than 2^32. Best case, the call to `Execute` would overwrite the low bytes and leave the bits above 32 alone, resulting in a wrong answer.

The solution is to call `Execute` with a pointer to a 32-bit data type. Create one in your proxy, give it a sensible starting value if needed, make the call, and copy the resulting value into the `long` that `pnUsedOutBytes` points to.

Oh, and don't paraphrase error messages. The error message did **not** say that you can't **cast** `long*` to `int*`; you can. What it almost certainly said is that the compiler can't **convert** `long*` to `int*`. That's correct: there is no **implicit** conversion between the two types. Adding a cast tells the compiler to do it; with that you have an **explicit** conversion.

Comment: Hmm... how could `pnUsedOutBytes` be larger than 32bit since it is typed as Int32 in C#? So that would/could never happen?!
Sorry, about the error message. ;) Shame on me.

Comment: There are two versions of `pnUsedOutBytes`; the one in the C++ code has type `long*`, and it's what's being passed in the call to `Execute`.

Comment: @pete no one cares what value is initially in that location since the buffer is provided for the function to fill in. And the function can't write a value that's out of range.  It's an output parameter.

Comment: @BenVoigt - the initial value is **probably** not used, which is why I said "give it a sensible starting value **if needed**", but there is nothing in the question that says that it's not used.

Comment: Oh now I see what you're saying, it's not that an out-of-range original value wouldn't reach the function that's a problem, but that part of the original uninitialized content could survive the functions call.  In any case, it just isn't a problem in Visual C++ (the only C++/CLI I know of), where `long` is guaranteed to be 32 bits.

Comment: Well, I implemented the requested solution using a local variable in the C++/CLI proxy PLUS changing the parameter's type in the C# function to `out Int32 pnUsedOutBytes`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is just to fix the signature of the exported function:

```
extern "C" __declspec ( dllexport ) int32_t Execute(uint32_t command, int32_t nInBytes, byte bInData[], int32_t nOutBytes, int32_t* pnUsedOutBytes, byte bOutData[])
```

`LoadLibrary` will give you no grief whatsoever about the difference between `int32_t` and `int` and `long`, since they are all 32-bit integral types.

(Actually, `LoadLibrary` won't give you any grief for a bunch of actual errors either, ... but in this case you aren't using an incompatible type)